# Linq .FirstOrDefault() on a Mocked List

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing, moq

I'm trying to write a unit test using Moq for some code and coming up against a NullReferenceException on my call to firstOrDefault(). Here is a snippet of my affected code:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void LinqAlist()
    {
        var _mockList = new Mock<List<int>>();
        var realData = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3};

        _mockList.Object.AddRange(realData);
        //returns 1
         var realOne = realData.FirstOrDefault(x => x == 1);
        //throws NullReferenceException
        var mockOne = _mockList.Object.FirstOrDefault(x => x == 1);

    }
```

I can't see why I'm getting the Null reference, as far as I can tell, I've instantiated it properly.

Thanks for your help!

Why am I mocking a list?

I am attempting to mock the behaviour of a Class which inherits from List as follows:

```
public class IndxList<T> : List<T>.....

public class ClassUnderTest<T> : IndxList<T>....
```

I'm trying to debug down to the cause of my null to the List class.

Comment: Please can you post the `Mock<T>` constructor ?

Comment: I try your example and it works fine. I get mockOne equal 1. What version of moq library you use?

Comment: Can you talk us through why you are mocking a List? Why not just use an actual List?

Comment: Hi @mjwills, further detail added to the question.

Comment: @Dmitry, I am on version 4.5.9.0

Comment: @MrGiggles Hmm... in 4.5.9 i really get NullReferenceException, maybe you should upgrade your moq library to last stable?

Comment: @Dmitry that's fixed it!

Comment: @mjwills, the IndxList class has a huge amount of functionality attached to it and other dependancies which would take forever to Mock out independantly.

Comment: But why mock it at all? What benefit are you achieving by mocking it rather than just newing it up? What are the other dependencies? Could you mock those dependencies rather than the `IndxList`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to be carefull when you mock a class as there are some more traps.
You cannot mock an non virtual method with this framework and even with others the base method will still be executed.

When you mock a type it should be about simplifying the dependencies needed to test an other part. Also that you only test the specific part which the unit test is about.

With a list it is easier to just create one. You can assume that this class is tested and working.

Comment: Re: _"it is not recommended to mock a class instead of an interface as the method or property behind will still be executed."_ No, unless you set `mock.CallBase = true`, the base class' methods will not be invoked. Mocking a class is perfectly fine, there are just more caveats to keep in mind.